Running count of repeating groups
# dataframe
df <- tibble(
# groups
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A"),
# running count of all groups
  count = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7)

In my data there are a series of repeating groups. In this example, rows 1-3 are the first occurrence of group "A", row 4 is the first occurrence of group "B", rows 5-7 are the second occurrence of group "A", row 8 is the first occurrence of group "C" etc. count is the running count of all groups.
I want a running count of each individual group occurrence that provides the output seen in individual_runing_count. The order of groups and number of occurrences of each group will not always be the same, so I can't use a fixed criteria such as number of rows or order of the groups column.
# df with required output
df <- tibble(
# groups
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A"),
# order in which groups occurred
  order = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7),
# required column output
  individual_running_count = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3)
)


mutate(df, individual_running_count=consecutive_id(count), .by=group)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   group count individual_running_count
   <chr> <dbl>                    <int>
 1 A         1                        1
 2 A         1                        1
 3 A         1                        1
 4 B         2                        1
 5 A         3                        2
 6 A         3                        2
 7 A         3                        2
 8 C         4                        1
 9 B         5                        2
10 B         5                        2
11 C         6                        2
12 A         7                        3


Base R:
df$irc <- ave(df$order, df$group, FUN = \(x) match(x, unique(x)))


data.table approach
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, irc := rleid(count), by = group]

